# How can I add an element that has been added to the webpage to a select/option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm doing a project in which the user is able to add another cell to a table. My problem is that I can't figure out how to add an added element to the select/option tag I have for the table using jquery or javaScript. Can someone please help me with it? Thanks

Comment: Can you include your HTML in your post please? Also include any code you've been trying to get to work

Comment: If you are using jquery, you can try $('select#itemID').append('<optionnew option></..>'):